# Fortran: pass two arguments of a different kind

Tags: fortran

Is it possible to pass two (or more) arguments of a different kind to a subroutine?

I've tried:

```
program Main
    real(4) :: sp = 1.0
    real(8) :: dp = 1.0
    call Test(sp,dp)
contains
    subroutine Test(sp,dp)
        real, intent(in) :: sp,dp
        print *, sp
        print *, dp
    end subroutine
end program
```

and

```
subroutine Test(sp,dp)
    real, intent(in) :: sp
    real, intent(in) :: dp
    print *, sp
    print *, dp
end subroutine
```

But they both give the exact same error while compiling:

```
call Test(sp,dp)
              1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 'dp' at (1); passed REAL(8) to REAL(4)
```

The only way I was able to make it work is:

```
program Main
    real(4) :: sp = 1.0
    real(8) :: dp = 1.0
    call Test(sp,dp)
contains
    subroutine Test(sp,dp)
        real(4), intent(in) :: sp
        real(8), intent(in) :: dp
        print *, sp
        print *, dp
    end subroutine
end program
```

But this defeats my purpose as I don't want to declare the kinds of the variables `sp` and `dp` twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the kinds twice because there are *two* variables called `sp` (and `dp`): one in the main program and one in the subroutine.  In the subroutine call it is required that the dummy argument (the `sp` in the subroutine) matches the actual argument (the `sp` in the main program).

This is a good thing when it comes to generic resolution.

Note, however, that in your case you don't need to do this, as the subroutine is internal to the main program the arguments needn't be passed: you can use the `sp` from the main program in the subroutine without redeclaring it.  Generally, though, you will need to.

Also, your first two cases

```
real, intent(in) :: sp
real, intent(in) :: dp
```

and

```
real, intent(in) :: sp,dp
```

mean the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do that, if you need the kinds to be of that value. Every variable and every dummy argument should have a declared type. Therefore your last example is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do what you're trying to do without re-declaring the types of the variables in the subroutine. It's just like in C/C++/C#/Java: you need to declare the types of each of the parameters, even though the types of the arguments have already been declared elsewhere.